# Why does the short_cur evaluation fail to work when using its value to preform arithmetic?[Lua]

Tags: lua

I was trying to writing following code to perform arithmetic on short_cur evaluation expression

```
print(1 + (true or false) and 1 or 0)
```

while the interpreter said that I got a `attempt to perform arithmetic on a boolean value`  Error.

AFAIK in lua when I write down the code `a and b or c` it actually gets the value depending the value of a(while b is not false), so the code above shall work as if `print(1 + 1)` under this cicumstances.

However the result does not seems to fit my expectation. I wonder why would this happen? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Lua's operator precedence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.8), the `+` is evaluated before the `and`. Your expression needs an extra pair of parenthesis: `1 + ((true or false) and 1 or 0)`.